# Droid X attachment download location

Tags: email, motorola-droid-x

I'm just trying to figure out where in the phone the attachments get saved after you open them?

I remember opening a PDF attachment from my email using my Droid X. The email was deleted so I'm trying to find the PDF that was downloaded by my phone when I opened the attachment.

I have an MSN account.

Anyone knows the default location in the phone?

Thank you

Comment: Via the GMail app? I'm not sure that it keeps the attachments it previews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, email attachments and browser downloads are stored at:

```
/sdcard/download
```

Can also be identified by some File Managers as:

```
/HWUserData/download
```

If the device doesn't have a user-replaceable SD card the location should be:

```
/mnt/sdcard/Download
```

<sup>Some apps may have their own default location, or save to appropriated locations based on the file extension.</sup>

Comment: Mine is at `/mnt/sdcard/Download`, presumably because I don't have a removable SD card.

Comment: @AlEverett Yes, you're correct about that! I just recently added a removable SDCard, and my previous locations was the one you've mentioned. Thank you for the comment, I'm updating the answer now.